# Creating array of pointers to struct inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, abstract-data-type

Basiclly, I have a struct defined this way:

```
struct D_Array
{
    int Capacity;
    int Cur_Size;
    struct Student* List;
};
```

Now, after creating the struct;

```
struct D_Array* T_Array;
if (T_Array = malloc(sizeof(struct D_Array)) == NULL)
{
    printf("There has been a problem with memory allocation. Exiting the program.");
    exit (21);
}
```

I have a problem creating the students list inside this struct. I need the list to be an array of pointers, since I should make some kind of ADT program, I've tried to make it something like this:

```
T_Array->Capacity = 10;
T_Array->Cur_Size = 0;
T_Array->List[10]= (struct Student*) malloc(sizeof (struct Student*));
```

It doesn't matter how I tried to change it, I'm getting the same error:
incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Student' from type 'struct Student *'|

I've trying to create an array that I will be able to do something like;

```
T_Array->List[1]=Student_Pointer;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of the array to struct Student** that will be array of pointers :

struct student * --> a pointer to student.
struct student ** --> a pointer to a pointer to student (what you need).

```
struct D_Array
{
    int Capacity;
    int Cur_Size;
    struct Student** List;
}
```

and the allocation:

```
T_Array->List = malloc (sizeof (struct Student*) *  lengthofarray);
```

and then:

```
T_Array->List[1]=Student_Pointer;
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`. In `sizeof (struct student*)x lengthofarray` `x` should be `*`.

Comment: You have to cast if you want it to compile, what do you mean?

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). If you think you need it, you are either using a compiler for a wrong language, or forgetting to `#include` required headers.

Comment: Thanks, it did solve the problem. I guess the main problem was how I've defined D_Array in the first place, and yes, it also works without casting.

Comment: You are wrong, malloc returns void* wich is obviously not student* so you need a cast, maybe there are compiler who will do an implicit casting for you...

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz void would automatically convert to the the datatype of the variable that it's getting assigned to... Then why take the pain of casting once again when it's done automatically?

Comment: begginers in c needs to know what they are doing, if someone started learning c he will use things that are not must just so he will know what happens in the background, for him an explicit writing will be preferred.

Comment: "*malloc returns void\* wich is obviously not student\* so you need a cast*" not needed, nor recommended in any way in C, C does this implicitly from and to void-pointers. This is different in C++.

Comment: in some compilers the default return type of a function is int, it is still a good idea to explicity write a return type , again for best practicing the language.

Comment: someone who is learning c will never remember that function like malloc returns a void* if they wont be casting the return value, and then they will not understand how malloc "knows" their user defined type pointer ( a real question i was asked).

Comment: If you do not include the prototype for `malloc()` on 64bit system its return type will default to `int`, yes. The compiler would detect this and error. If you would have applied an explicit conversion via a cast to `void*` the compiler just warns (or do log nothing all), it definitely won't error. Still `malloc()` would return 32 bits only (what the width of an `int`), and miss the upper 32bits for the `void*` it should return with or without cast. Conclusion: The cast hid the error, the program will fail. This is not good. Do not cast where it isn't required (for exp. when call `accept()`.

Comment: Although i still thinks it is not a good thing to do while learning the language, i have edited the code.

Comment: As far as learning is concerned i agree with you @Dr.Haimovitz :)

Answer (score 0):

`struct Student* List;`
List is a pointer of Student
When you do List[10] what youre doing is basicaly
`*(List+10)` that means get Student from the 11th position

If you want an array of pointers you need to do something like

`struct Student **List;`

and then
`List = (Student **)malloc(10*sizeof(Student **))`

List would then have memory allocated for 10 pointers of student wich would be size of int for each in the end